# SQL query with multiple unrelated tables

Tags: mysql, select, multiple-tables, multiple-conditions

In my mySQL database there are four tables: `breakfast`, `dinner`, `supper`, `supper`.
Column names of these tables are the same. Everyone one of them has a column called '`accepted`' which is equal to either `0` or `1`.

I want to make the SQL query that gives me one random row from these four tables
WHERE 'accepted' column  is equal to 0.

SQL query with only 1 table that works:

```
SELECT * FROM breakfast WHERE accepted=0 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

My version of SQL query with four tables that doesn't work:

```
 SELECT * FROM breakfast, dinner, supper, dessert WHEREbreakfast.accepted=0
AND dinner.accepted=0 AND supper.accepted=0 AND dessert.accepted=0 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Do the tables have the same columns?

Comment: Decide what RDBMS you use.

Comment: please specify the columns in each table, when we use union you must use same name for fields in different quires for that we need field name to give Aliases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this,

I assume that your number of columns in all the four tables are same.

MySQL

```
   SELECT col1,col2
FROM (
    SELECT col1,col2
    FROM breakfast
    WHERE breakfast.accepted = 0

    UNION

    SELECT col1,col2
    FROM dinner
    WHERE dinner.accepted = 0

    UNION

    SELECT col1,col2
    FROM supper
    WHERE supper.accepted = 0

    UNION

    SELECT col1,col2
    FROM dessert
    WHERE dessert.accepted = 0
    ) T
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

SQL Server:

```
SELECT top 1 col1,col2
FROM (
    SELECT col1,col2
    FROM breakfast
    WHERE breakfast.accepted = 0

    UNION

    SELECT col1,col2
    FROM dinner
    WHERE dinner.accepted = 0

    UNION

    SELECT col1,col2
    FROM supper
    WHERE supper.accepted = 0

    UNION

    SELECT col1,col2
    FROM dessert
    WHERE dessert.accepted = 0
    ) T
ORDER BY newid()
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one :

```
SELECT breakfast FROM 
(SELECT breakfast FROM breakfast WHERE accepted=0 
union
SELECT supper as breakfast FROM supper WHERE accepted=0 
union
SELECT dessert as breakfast FROM dessert WHERE accepted=0 
union
SELECT dinner as breakfast FROM dinner WHERE accepted=0 
) food ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

in this query I am excepting there is a field with name breakfast in table breakfast, if u need to use "*" please use Aliases to make all the field name similar in the different union queries.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
 SELECT TOP 1 * FROM breakfast,
 (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM dinner WHERE accepted=0 ORDER BY RAND()) As Dinner,
 (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM supper WHERE accepted=0 ORDER BY RAND()) As supper,
 (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM dessert WHERE accepted=0 ORDER BY RAND()) As dessert 
 WHERE breakfast.accepted=0 ORDER BY RAND()
```